# How to Select Certain Fields in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How to Do following Query in Laravel Eloquent?

```
SELECT catID, catName, imgPath FROM categories WHERE catType = "Root"
```

I have tried following

```
CategoryModel::where('catType', '=', 'Root')
                ->lists('catName', 'catID', 'imgPath');
```

but its return only two fields.

```
Array ( [7] => Category 1 )
```

Comment: Surely `CategoryModel::select('catName', 'catID', 'imgPath')->where('catType', '=', 'Root')->get()` would be better?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`lists()` turns the resulting collection into an array with key value. You can only have two database columns in there. Otherwise you have to use `select()` but then you will get a collection of models not just an array.

```
$categories = CategoryModel::select('catID', 'catName', 'imgPath')
                           ->where('catType', '=', 'Root')
                           ->get();
```

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the documentation pages?  I can't find them.  Specifically, I'd like to better understand the `select()` function.

Comment: Here it is for `select()` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements

Answer (score 7):

Selecting multiple columns

```
CategoryModel::get(['catName', 'catID', 'imgPath']);
```

Works with Laravel 5.3 too!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get certain columns then You can use one of the **two method `get()` or `all()`**

but the syntax is different for both, **`get()` method takes `array` as argument** and **`all()` method takes `string` or `array` both as argument**:

**Model::all('field1','field2')** with `string` as arguments

```
CategoryModel::all('catName', 'catID', 'imgPath')->where('catType','Root');
```

**Model::all(['field1','field2'])** with `array` as arguments

```
CategoryModel::all(['catName', 'catID', 'imgPath'])->where('catType','Root');
```

**Model::get(['field1','field2'])**

```
CategoryModel::get(['catName', 'catID', 'imgPath'])->where('catType','Root');
```

Comment: thanks also all() method works on both(string and array) laravel version 6.x

Comment: @otosturop, thanks for suggestion, i have updated the answer for it.

Comment: @otosturop, i have found out that `all` method calls `get` method but takes `array` or `string` both as arguments since `laravel version 5.1`, so from `laravel 5.1` `string` or `array` both will work in `all()` method's argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
CategoryModel::wherecatType('Root')
            ->pluck('catName', 'catID', 'imgPath');
```

Answer (score 0):

From laravel version 5.3^ `lists()` is deprecated and function `pluck()` is used instead.

`pluck()` returns a collection and if you need a simple array just prepend `->toArray()` to it.