# How to get json format for monogo db object

Tags: php, json, mongodb

Here $data returns single record from auth_config collection but i have to get only one particular field value
        $password  = $this->input->get_request_header('Password', TRUE);
        $username  = $this->input->get_request_header('Username', TRUE);

```
    $data=$this->mongo_db->where('login_name',$username)->get('auth_config');

    return $data;
```

Comment: that of course should be `json_encode()` as `json_decode()` comes **from** JSON and you want **to** JSON instead. MongoDB does not emit JSON. You are **converting to JSON** from navtive PHP data structures.

Comment: it returns the ouput as "_id": {
"$id": "59896d8166a002a61a2e7807"
},
"company_id": "10",
"login_name": "openbrm",
"password": "123qwe"
} but i want to get only password field value how can i retrieve it

Comment: That's a different question. I'd generally say [look at and read about projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) but you appear to be using an ORM. Laravel? For which maybe [How to Select Certain Fields in Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530364/how-to-select-certain-fields-in-laravel-eloquent). At any rate, look for answers or [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: thank you i got correct result