# Laravel - Find name and display

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display all the data that has the same name. like for example, here is my data.

[image]

i have this data,  for example i only want the name of `James` then all data that is named James must be displayed.

my problem here is the data is being displayed even when the name is `Rizal` the name is being displayed . all i want is to make the data dependent on the id or name

my View

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME IN</th>
            <th>TIME OUT</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                       
        @foreach ($employeeSched as $setTime)
            <tr>      
                <td> {{Form::label('date_today', $setTime->date_today)}}</td>
                <td> {{Form::label('time_in',  $setTime->time_in)}}</td>
                <td> {{Form::label('time_out',  $setTime->time_out)}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach                  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller , to display my  data

```
 $employeeSched = Schedule::all();
```

Comment: can you share the expected output ? for given data ?

Comment: @C2486 yes sure, the final output must display data with the SAME name only. for example `Lebron` then the data must all be lebron only when i click the name

Comment: Do employee_no is foreign key or you are inserting key and name on each new record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Select Certain Fields in Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530364/how-to-select-certain-fields-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: @umefarooq it is a foreign key sir.

Comment: @obitouchiha if it is foreign key why you are repeating employee name in Schedule table, just create relation in emplyee model schedules hasMany, it will be easy for your display data under each employee name

Answer (score 1):

```
$employeeSched = Schedule::where('name', ‘rizal’)->get();
```

The above query will give all data where name is rizal, to transfer it to blade

```
return view(‘viewBlade’)->(‘userList’, $employeeSched);
```

Now in blade

```
@foreach($userList as $user)
{{$user.name}}
{{$user.anotherFields}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what if i click on the name 'james` ?

Comment: then this is a fixed value ? i want a dynamic value sir

Comment: Then make one field in form and pass username from forms input then you can access it from controller by doing $input[‘name’] put that in where query in controller

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get rows for special user last name:

```
let userLastName = 'anything';
$employeeSched = Schedule::where('last_name', userLastName)->get();
```

in this way you can set user name dynamically.

note that family name might not be unique. So its better to use `employee_no` against `last_name` to fetch special user data Or if you don't have `employee_no` use both `first_name` and `last_name` in this way.

```
let userFirstName = 'anything';
let userLastName = 'anything else';
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['first_name'=>userFirstName, 'last_name'=>userLastName])->get();
```

Comment: this is not complete thought but I get the idea and i think this will be dynamic i will set the `anything` to my input text field or hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the controller function you use which call on route url like `\listuser`

```
function viewUser(Request $request){
  $id= $request->id;
  $employeeSched = Schedule::where('employee_no',$id)->get();
}
```

in blade when you are looping through users.

```
    //$users contains all the user data, assumed id which hold the employee id, and user have name. 
assume route listuser where you list the attendance
    @foreach($users as $u)
      <a href="{{url('listuser')}}?id={{$u->id}}">{{$u->name}}</a>
    @foreach
```

This should do the work. And for your note, don't query database with fields like name always employee id. Because same name can repeat to different employees but the employee id will be unique for each employee. 

**Another Way**
In route

```
Route::get('user/{id}/attenance','UserController@viewUser')->name('user.attend');
```

And controller function will like

```
function viewUser($id){
  $employeeSched = Schedule::where('employee_no',$id)->get();
}
```

In Blade, from here you access the attendance page

```
@foreach($users as $u)
   <a href="{{route('user.attend',$u->id)}}">{{$u->name}}</a>
@foreach
```