# Laravel display spercific data in the database table using where clause

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a table named books which has category column and i want to display books of a specific category but the view display no book and does not return error. Below is the function in my controller

```php
public function science()
{
   $books = collect('DB::select * from books')->where('Category','=','Physical Science');
   return view('science_view',['books'=>$books]);
}
```

I will appreciate any help, THANKS!

Comment: What are you expecting `collect('DB::select * from books')` to be doing?

Comment: I am trying to return the collection of books of a specific category...

Comment: But `collect` accepts an array and converts it to a `Collection`. You've passed it a string. How do you expect that query (which looks to be a mix of plain SQL and query builder) to be executed?

Comment: Maybe try checking the docs? If you're not sure where to look in the docs, a simple search like "*laravel where condition*" takes you right there: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#basic-where-clauses. Evens simpler terms like "*laravel select*" will show you thousands of examples, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530364/how-to-select-certain-fields-in-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 2):

if you created a Book model you can achieve it by doing:

```
Book::where('Category','=','Physical Science')->get()
```

else

```
DB::table('books')->where('Category','=','Physical Science')->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your question let mi try it this way.

Comment: sure! if it works, don't forget to mark it as a correct answer!